# How to print usage help using minimist?

Tags: javascript, command-line-arguments, minimist

Here is a simple example from [here](https://devhints.io/minimist), which shows the very basics of the [minimist](https://github.com/substack/minimist) command line argument parser:

```
var minimist = require('minimist')

var args = minimist(process.argv.slice(2), {
  string: 'lang',           // --lang xml
  boolean: ['version'],     // --version
  alias: { v: 'version' }
})

console.log(args)
```

I want to print the usage of this simple script something like [this](https://github.com/tj/commander.js#automated---help):

```
$ node myprog
Usage: myprog [options]

Short description

Options:
  --lang <lang>       sets the language
  --version           output the version number
  -h, --help          output usage information
```

**How can I do this using minimist?**

Or should I use another tool like [commander](https://github.com/tj/commander.js)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finally I have [found](https://github.com/substack/minimist/issues/90) that minimist is only *argument parser* and cannot generate decorated usage/help.

So you should use another tool, like tool like [commander](https://github.com/tj/commander.js).

Comment: You just saved me a whole lot of time, thank you